# Swift: How To Reduce List of Non-Unique Products and Sum Quantities

Tags: arrays, swift, mapreduce

I have a list of orders, each containing a product name and quantity. The list may contain duplicate products (non-unique) and each entry contains a quantity.

The desired result is to get a "reduced" list of products with the quantities summed for each.

**Example**

```
Product     Qty

Apple       1
Orange      4
Banana      2
Apple       2
Banana      3
Pear        2
Apple       1
```

Want to reduce the array (or new array) to this:

```
Product     Qty

Apple       4
Banana      5
Orange      4
Pear        2
```

I don't do a lot of Swift dev and could certainly muscle through this with a big looping iteration, but I'm hoping to find a "Swifty" way to accomplish using map/reduce or whatever the right way to do it in Swift might be. I'm sure it would be much faster.

The master product list is in an array of objects (productName: String , qty: Int)

Many thanks for some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the product name, put them all into a dictionary, then sum up the values.

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: originalList,
                      by: { $0.productName })
               .mapValues { $0.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.qty }) }
```

This gives you a `[String: Int]`. If you want a `[(productName: String, qty: Int)]` instead,

```
let entries = dict.map { (productName: $0, qty: $1) }
```